# Как инвертировать поля в односвязном списке

Tags: pascal, указатели, списки

Нужно инвертировать полином (поменять коэффициенты), который представлен односвязным списком на паскале, пример: 1x^5 + 4x^8 + 2x^3 ==>> 2x^5 + 4x^8 + 1x^3.

```
type
  polinom = ^element;
  element = record
    coef: real;
    exp: integer;
    next: polinom;
  end;

var
  pCurrent: polinom; // - вспомогательный указатель
  pHead: polinom;    // - заголовок исходного списка
```

Лучше сделать это как можно меньшим количеством проходов, подскажите алгоритм для решения данной задачи.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора.

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать для решения задачи? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: А я голосую за незакрытие, потому что автор просит подсказать оптимальный алгоритм (а не написать код за него), и это интересно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например пройти по списку 1 раз и сохранить в массив нужные поля (в вашем случае коэффициенты). Потом пройти второй раз и присвоить полям значения из списка в обратном порядке.

Возможно есть более оптимальное решение, хотелось бы его увидеть

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал, написал код - преподаватель принял.

Comment: @user190794 Рад за вас! Вы можете отметить ответ зеленой галкой, если он правильный )